# Visualize character glyph in Pages application

Tags: keyboard, text, text-editor

Is it possible to visualize a particular character (even if it's a special one) in a Pages document ? (I need it for a third-party doc I'm using, to know if certains spaces are just spaces, tabs or something else, and also to get the Unicode value of some exotic characters). All I see in the right bar or the Show Fonts  windows is the "style" info but not the glyph itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the app [UnicodeChecker](http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/) for this

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but it works. Thanks